# Insert into table where not already exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this table `skills` here `(id = auto increment & primary key)`:

```
| id  | skill |
--------------
| 1   | PHP   |
--------------
```

In this table I've the skill `PHP`. To insert a new skill I need to check if the skill already exists. I've tried it this way but it's not working. I'm not so familiar with MySQL / SQL:

Should not work:

```
INSERT INTO skills (`skill`) VALUES (`PHP`) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `skill` = `PHP`;
```

Should work:

```
INSERT INTO skills (`skill`) VALUES (`HTML`) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `skill` = `HTML`;
```

Comment: the "skill" field is not the key field, so adding the same value again won't produce a duplicate key. You'll just get another row with the same "skill" value, but a different "id" value. You probably want a unique constraint on that column. Either that or just make it the primary key, if that makes sense in your design.

Comment: you can make unique constraint for id and skills

Comment: @ADyson how can I do it instead? :)

Comment: @JayJay read my comment again, I already suggested some alternatives, depending on what suits your design and requirements.

Comment: @JayJay Whats your requirement??

Comment: If you drop the `id` column you might be able to use [INSERT IGNORE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-ignore/).

Answer (score 1):

This is the right command:

```
INSERT INTO skills (`skill`)
    VALUES ('PHP')  -- fixed the backticks
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `skill` = 'PHP';
```

I assume the backticks are a typo.  They should be single quotes.

Although I would write it as:

```
INSERT INTO skills (skill)
    VALUES ('PHP')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE skill = VALUES(skill);
```

This will only "work" if you have a unique constraint on `skill`:

```
create unique index unq_skills_skill on skills(skill);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would simply add an unique key on `skills` and use [insert ignore](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO skills (`skill`) VALUES (`PHP`)
```

You can then use `mysql_affected_rows()` to verify whether any record added or not, if it returns 0 then no record added because of duplicate.

Comment: Negativity should be used  positively by at least commenting the reason to downvote so ppl could learn & improve & help to understand what is right or wrong